# Scilab equivalent of Matlab's "charpoly"

Tags: matlab, matrix, equation, scilab

Please help me in figuring out the equivalent of charpoly (present in Matlab) in Scilab.
Or please tell me how to calculate the characteristic equation of a matrix in scilab if some other way is present.

Comment: Does the below answer fit your need ? Please validate the answer if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

use `poly` function:

```
--> a=[1 2;3 4]
 a  = 

   1.   2.
   3.   4.

--> poly(a,"s")
 ans  =

  -2 -5s +s²
```